# How to lookup tag info in xml

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

The code below gets the information that I need, but I do not know how to do it without looping. It is not necessary because the tag is unique, and appears only once in each xml.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(dirname + '\metadata.xml')
root = tree.getroot

for i in tree.iter(tag='TAGABC'):
    print(i.text)
```

It seems that Find or FindAll will do it, but I don't know how to code it. I am using Element Tree, because it works just by importing it. Please help.

EDIT:
Original code that works:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(dirname + '\metadata.xml')
root = tree.getroot

for i in tree.iter(tag='{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}creator'):
    print(i.text)
for j in tree.iter(tag='{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}title'):
    print(j.text)
```

Suggested code that does not return anything:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(dirname + '\metadata.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ns = {'ns': 'purl.org/dc/elements/1.1'}
title = root.find('.//ns:title', ns)
creator = root.find('.//ns:creator', ns)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should be as simple as:

```
<root>
    <tag>1</tag>
    <tag>2</tag>
    <tag>3</tag>
</root>

# find direct child: returns first "tag"
tag = root.find('./tag')

# find child text: returns "1"
tag_text = root.findtext('./tag')

# find children: returns all "tag" elements
tags = root.findall('./tag')

# find children texts: returns ["1", "2", "3"]
tags_texts = [el.text for el in root.findall('./tag')]
```

Things become more complicated, when XML has namespaces:

```
<root xmlns="http://uri">
    <tag>1</tag>
    <tag>2</tag>
    <tag>3</tag>
</root>
```

In that case it's needed to declare a dict containing namespace declarations:

```
ns = {'ns1': 'http://uri'}
```

And use that dict when searching for elements:

```
# find direct child: returns first "tag"
tag = root.find('./ns1:tag', ns)

# find children: returns all "tag" elements
tags = root.findall('./ns1:tag', ns)

# find children texts: returns ["1", "2", "3"]
tags_texts = [el.text for el in root.findall('./ns1:tag', ns)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I hardly know anything about handling xml, and how it works, so I should really study your sample. My data that matches the filter (in this example "TAGABC") exists only once in each xml. This is why I am suspecting that I don't have to loop it. The actual code has in the filter (tag='{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}title')

Comment: In that case you could declare `ns = {'ns': 'purl.org/dc/elements/1.1'}` and then use it `title = root.find('.//ns:title', ns)`

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. This is what I have:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    
    tree = ET.parse(dirname + '\metadata.xml')
    root = tree.getroot
    ns = {'ns': 'purl.org/dc/elements/1.1'}

    title = root.find('.//ns:title', ns)
    creator = root.find('.//ns:creator', ns)    
I get a syntax error. (I am very sorry that I cannot show it as a code block. I tried and tried)

Comment: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
    'function' object has no attribute 'find'
    title = root.find('.//ns:title', ns) Above is the error. Yesterday it only said "syntax error," but now I get a little more. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Probably it should be`root = tree.getroot()` instead of `root = tree.getroot`

Comment: Thank you! A little progress. No error, but it did not grab the title data from xml file. It returned nothing. could you look one more time, please?

Comment: Generally it should work in that form. Could you probably update your question with an example of XML you're parsing and a snippet of your current code?